# Como puedo hacer que para precionando la letra 'e' en python

Tags: python, keyboard

Hola amigos tengo un ploblema, Quiero hacer que python imprima del 1 al 100 pero cuando yo precione la letra 'e' para todo. abajo esta el codigo

```
from time import sleep
import pyautogui
import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Listener
import pyautogui

sleep(3)

for i in range(1, 11111):
   print(i)
#pyautogui.typewrite(str(i))
#pyautogui.typewrite('\n')

def on_press_e(e):
   print('You pressed the "e" key!')

def on_release_e(e):
   print('You released the "e" key!')

with Listener(on_press=on_press_e,on_release=on_release_e) as listener:
   listener.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Si pones el contador adentro del listener entonces se podrá ejecutar y al mismo tiempo detectar las teclas presionadas

En tu función `on_press_e` no estás revisando si la tecla presionada es "e", por lo que detecta cualquier tecla, y si quieres que el `listener` se detenga entonces tienes que retornar `False` al cumplirse la condición de que la tecla presionada es "e"

Ejemplo completo (Como no indicaste en tu pregunta lo que hay que hacer cuando el contador llegue a 100 lo reinicié a 1 y seguirá contando de 1 a 100 hasta que presiones la tecla "e")

Ejemplo completo:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
from time import sleep

#Variable global para detectar si se ha presionado la tecla "e"
e_press = False

#Función para detectar teclas presionadas
def on_press(key):
    #Uso de la variable global
    global e_press
    #No todas las teclas tienen .char (Por ejemplo shift), por eso hay que usar try - except
    try:
        if key.char == 'e':
            e_press = True
            print('La tecla "e" ha sido presionada')
            #Detener el listener
            return False
    except:
        pass

#Inicialización del contador
i = 1

#Listener
with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    #Se ejecuta mientras no se haya presionado la tecla "e"
    while not e_press:
        print(i)
        i += 1
        if i > 100:
            i = 1
        sleep(1)
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Buenos dias, Muchas gracias, si funciono ahora voy studiar el codigo :)

Comment: @alguien, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)