# ¿Cómo parar el programa usando una combinación de teclas?

Tags: python

### Necesito ayuda con esta automatización que estoy creando

***Edit: Si no quieres leer de lleno toda la pregunta desde el comienzo, ve al final... Muchas gracias a quienes han dado respuesta o han comentado: me han ayudado.***

Bueno, antes que nada, debo admitir que este código no es de una aplicación, sino para ejecutar una automatización. Resulta que quiero parar la automatización con una combinación de teclas por si algo sale mal, pero no puedo.

Y, además aquí voy a poner gran parte del código para que lo revisen y me sugieran mejoras o una mejor organización.

```
import webbrowser
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
import modules_1  # Importar módulos
import os
import time
import pyperclip
import datetime
from babel.dates import format_date
import sys
import asyncio
import pygetwindow as gw

info_root = None  # Variable global para la ventana de información
root = None

def open_edge():
    # Aquí he omitido varias acciones (no afectará la respuesta)


def copy_to_files():
    # Aquí he omitido varias acciones (no afectará la respuesta)

def execute_tasks():
    perform_task_and_close_info_1()
    perform_task_2()
    
    rename_and_move_downloaded_videos()
    open_whatsapp()
    modules_1.search_compare()
    show_final_confirmation()

def show_info_window_and_perform_tasks():
    global info_root, root  # Acceder a las variables globales
    info_root = tk.Tk()
    info_root.title("Espera:")
    
    info_text = "Espera que las pestañas se carguen correctamente. Luego de da clic en continuar."
    label = tk.Label(info_root, text=info_text, wraplength=300, justify="center")
    label.pack(padx=20, pady=20)
    
    button = tk.Button(info_root, text="Continuar", command=execute_tasks)
    button.pack(padx=20, pady=10)
    
    # Centrar la ventana en la pantalla
    info_root.update_idletasks()
    width = info_root.winfo_width()
    height = info_root.winfo_height()
    x = (info_root.winfo_screenwidth() - width) // 2
    y = (info_root.winfo_screenheight() - height) // 2
    info_root.geometry(f"{width}x{height}+{x}+{y}")

    info_root.attributes("-topmost", True)  # Hacer la ventana superior    
    info_root.mainloop()

def perform_task_and_close_info_1():
    global info_root  # Acceder a la variable global
    info_root.destroy()  # Cerrar la ventana de información
    with open("texto_1.txt", "r") as file:
        text_1 = file.read()
        pyperclip.copy(text_1)
    time.sleep(2)
    repetitive_actions_1()
    repetitive_actions_2()    
    time.sleep(2)


Acciones repetitivas...


def repetitive_actions_1():
    # Aquí he omitido varias acciones (no afectará la respuesta)
def repetitive_actions_2():
    # Aquí he omitido varias acciones (no afectará la respuesta)
    
def perform_task_2():        
    time.sleep(1)
    with open("texto_2.txt", "r") as file:
        text_2 = file.read()
        pyperclip.copy(text_2)   
    time.sleep(2)
    repetitive_actions_1()
        
    time.sleep(2)


def show_final_confirmation():
    final_confirmation_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    final_confirmation_window.title("Tareas completadas")

    info_text = "Todas las tareas se han completado con éxito."
    label = tk.Label(final_confirmation_window, text=info_text, wraplength=300, justify="center")
    label.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

    def close_application():
        final_confirmation_window.destroy()
        sys.exit()  # Cerrar completamente la aplicación

    button = tk.Button(final_confirmation_window, text="Aceptar", command=close_application)
    button.pack(padx=20, pady=10)

    # Centrar la ventana en la pantalla
    final_confirmation_window.update_idletasks()
    width = final_confirmation_window.winfo_width()
    height = final_confirmation_window.winfo_height()
    x = (final_confirmation_window.winfo_screenwidth() - width) // 2
    y = (final_confirmation_window.winfo_screenheight() - height) // 2
    final_confirmation_window.geometry(f"{width}x{height}+{x}+{y}")

    final_confirmation_window.attributes("-topmost", True)  # Hacer la ventana superior
    final_confirmation_window.mainloop()

def rename_and_move_downloaded_videos():
    # Aquí he omitido varias acciones (no afectará la respuesta)

def open_whatsapp():    
    # Aquí he omitido varias acciones (no afectará la respuesta)
```

**Sobre esta parte del código específicamente es que me enfoco para preguntar:**
Como verán: aquí defino a **check_exit_combination()**, pero a la hora de llamarla en **main**, ejecutando la automatización, cuando presiono Ctrl + X, la automatización de todos modos continúa... y no detiene como debiera hacerlo.

```
async def check_exit_combination():
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl') and keyboard.is_pressed('x'):
            sys.exit()
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)  # Esperar 100 ms
```

Resto del código:

```
def main():
    # Iniciar el loop de eventos de asyncio
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(check_exit_combination())
    md_file_path = "README_1.md"
    os.startfile(md_file_path)
    time.sleep(4)

    confirm = messagebox.askyesno("Deja de usar la computadora mientras esto sucede:", "Confirma para ejecutar la tarea programada...")
    if confirm:        
        modules_1.persistent_window()  # Llama a la función para configurar la ventana persistente 

        global root
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.withdraw()

        copy_to_files()              
        open_edge()        
        show_info_window_and_perform_tasks() 
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Tarea cancelada", "La tarea no se ha ejecutado.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar a cómo parar la automatización con esa combinación de teclas, te agradezco de antemano...

### Bien, hasta ahí estaba ayer. Hoy he modificado la parte final del código:

```
# Bandera para controlar la ejecución del bucle
running = True

def stop_program():
    global running
    print("Stopping the program.")
    running = False

def custom_keyboard_interrupt_handler(signal_number, frame):
    print("Received SIGINT signal. Exiting gracefully.")
    stop_program()

def main():
    
    print("Program is running...")
    global running
    while running:
        pass  # Mantén el programa en ejecución

    print("Program has been stopped.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Registrar el manejador para SIGINT
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, custom_keyboard_interrupt_handler)

    # Registrar la combinación de teclas (Control + X) para detener el programa
    keyboard.add_hotkey("ctrl+x", stop_program)

    main()
```

Pero, ahora lo que pasa es que: pues así como está la parte final, el Ctrl + X funciona como debe ser. Pero, así no se puede quedar porque necesito añadir las llamadas completas en main() que están en código anterior de ayer, para que en verdad funcione; entonces he intentado de varias maneras incluir las otras funciones en main(), pero, no sé que ha pasado, pero entonces el Ctrl + X deja de funcionar como debe, y empieza a dar problemas.

Me explico un poco mejor: si desppués de *print("Program is running...")* coloco algunas tareas muy simples como simular win + s, la verdad que no hay problemas con nada... Pero, si pongo las funciones completas que necesito, empiezan todos los problemas, el Ctrl + X ya no funciona (solamente si es capaz de imprimir: Stopping the program, no hace nada más), y print("Stopping the program.") solo funciona antes de empezar las funciones del botón continuar de la primera ventana, y luego ya no... Es como si le quedara grande parar a todas esas funciones siguientes (igual que me quedó grande arreglar eso por ahora, jaja)

Cabe aclarar que la librería *async* ya no la estoy usando en esta nueva modificación, y ya he importado la libería **signal** al comiezo del código

Comment: Podrías usar la API [`signal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) para controlar las interrupciones del sistema. En este [post](https://vegibit.com/python-signal-module/) hay ejemplos de uso. Saludos

Comment: Mezclar código `async` con código síncrono no te va a funcionar. El código sícrono bloquea **todo**, sin dar posibilidad de ejecutar el `async`.

Comment: Ok... Muchísimas gracias

Comment: [Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/536869/171630) hay un ejemplo de algo similar.

Answer (score 0):

Esta solución es la más usada, usar la libreria [signal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) y [sys](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html).

Un ejemplo muy sencillo:

```py
import signal, sys

from time import sleep

def def_handler(sig, frame):
    #Función que se ejecuta al pulsar Ctrl+C
    print("\n\nMensaje De salida\n")
    #Finalizar programa
    sys.exit(1)

#Ctrl+C
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, def_handler)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Sustituir por tu programa
    sleep(10)
```

Si quisieras añadir otro comportamiento solo juega con las posibles signals y defines un controlador con el comportamiento deseado.